# How to define equality for Category instances?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In order to prove that for instance the *Category laws* hold for some operations on a data type, how do one decide how to define equality? Considering the following type for representing boolean expressions:

```haskell
data Exp
    = ETrue
    | EFalse
    | EAnd Exp Exp
    deriving (Eq)
```

Is it feasible trying to prove that *Exp* forms a Category with identity *ETrue* and operator:

```
(<&>) = EAnd
```

without redefining the *Eq* instance? Using the default instance of *Eq* the *left-identity* law breaks, i.e:

```haskell
ETrue <&> e == e
```

evaluates to *False*. However, defining an *eval function*:

```haskell
eval ETrue =  True
eval EFalse = False
eval (EAnd e1 e2) = eval e1 && eval e2
```

and the *Eq* instance as:

```haskell
instance Eq Exp where
    e1 == e2 = eval e1 == eval e2
```

fixes the problem. Is comparison in terms of *(==)* a general requirement for claiming to satisfy such laws, or is it sufficient to say that the laws hold for a particular type of equality operator?

Comment: You're not obligated to use the default implementation of `(==)` as structural equality. If you want it to mean equivalence up to some isomorphism, that's fine. It's perhaps bad form to do so if equivalent but not identical values can be easily distinguished by other means, though. The same applies for the notion of "equality" in the type class laws.

Comment: Where's the category? Just curious.

Comment: @C.A.McCann - Thanks, in many cases it would not even be possible to implement a proper comparison, so I guess it's at least not entirely wrong to argue that the monad/monoid/categery laws are satisfied with respect to some alternative isomorphism.

Comment: @n.m I was under the impression that in the mathematical sense `Exp` with arrow `<&>` and identity `ETrue` forms a Category. However, this does not rhyme well with the `Category` type class in Haskell since it requires instances to be higher kinded. Proving the Monoid laws would have been a better choice for this data type.

Comment: Well, it *is* a monoid and as such a category too (each monoid is a category), but '<&>' is not an arrow. '<&>' is the arrow composition. `Exp`s are arrows.

Comment: As an example of a type that uses non-structural equality, see lazy bytestrings.

Answer (score 8):

**Equality is [EVIL](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/evil).**  You rarely (if ever) need *structural equality*,
because it is *too strong*.  You only want an *equivalence* that is *strong enough* for
what you're doing.  This is particularly true for category theory.

In Haskell, `deriving Eq` will give you structural equality, which means that you'll
often want to write your own implementation of `==` / `/=`.

A simple example:  Define rational number as pairs of integers,
`data Rat = Integer :/ Integer`.  If you use structural equality (what Haskell is
`deriving`), you'll have `(1:/2) /= (2:/4)`, but as a fraction  `1/2 == 2/4`.  What
you really care about is the value that your tuples *denote*, not their
*representation*.  This means you'll need an **equivalence** that compares *reduced
fractions*, so you should implement that instead.

Side note:  If someone using the code assumes that you've defined a structural
equality test, i.e. that checking with `==` justifies replacing data sub-components
through pattern matching, their code may break.  If that is of importance,
you may hide the constructors to disallow pattern matching, or maybe define your
own `class` (say, `Equiv` with `===` and `=/=`) to separate both concepts.  (This
is mostly important for theorem provers like Agda or Coq, in Haskell it's really
hard to get practical/real-world code so wrong that finally something breaks.)

Really Stupid(TM) example:  Let's say that person wants to print long lists of huge
`Rat`s and believes memoizing the string representations of the `Integer`s will save
on binary-to-decimal conversion.  There's a lookup table for `Rat`s, such that equal
`Rat`s will never be converted twice, and there's a lookup table for integers.  If
`(a:/b) == (c:/d)`, missing integer entries will be filled by copying between `a`-`c` /
`b`-`d` to skip conversion (ouch!).  For the list `[ 1:/1, 2:/2, 2:/4 ]`, `1` gets
converted and then, because `1:/1 == 2:/2`, the string for `1` gets copied into the
`2` lookup entry.  The final result `"1/1, 1/1, 1/4"` is borked.

Comment: Does this imply that the monad laws should hold for the given implementation of `==`, or that things are ok if they hold in some isomorphism of your type that you don't directly implement as an `Eq` instance?

Comment: @VicSmith: They should hold for whatever notion of equality/equivalence you're using.  If you use/implement `==`, the laws should hold on that.  If you have (and have implemented) another comparison, use that when checking the laws.  I'd say it's best not to define/derive `==` on your type if you have a differing concept of equivalence to ensure it's impossible to confuse the two, because (as noted in the answer) mixing up differing concepts will probably break the logic.