# Is it possible to create a Functor instance for sorted binary trees in Haskell?

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, functional-programming, functor

Imagine we have a `SortBinTree` type constructor defined as, for example,

```
data SortBinTree a = EmptyNode | Node a (SortBinTree a) (SortBinTree a);
```

It make sense only when `a` is an instance of `Ord` type class, so most functions have `:: (Ord a) =>` in the beginning of their declaration, especially a function for creating such a tree from list. However to teach Haskell, that `SortBinTree` is an instance of `Functor` type class we have to write something like

```
instance Functor SortBinTree where
  fmap g tree = ...
```

The problem here is that we have to deal with `g :: a->b`, where `b` is not necessarily an instance of `Ord` type class. That makes it problematic to write such function, since we can't use inequalities while creating an element of the type `SortBinTree b`.

Is there a standard workaround here? Any way to define `fmap` only for the case `b` is in `Ord` type class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this with the `Functor` type class.  As you noted, [the Prelude gives us](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor)¹

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which provides no way to hang a restriction on the `b`.  We can define an `OrdFunctor` class:

```
class OrdFunctor f where
  fmapOrd :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This might get annoying if we had lots of different kinds of `Functor`s (`EqFunctor`, `MonoidFunctor`, etc.)  But if we turn on [`ConstraintKinds`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) and [`TypeFamilies`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/type-families.html), we can generalize this to a *restricted* functor class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

class RFunctor f where
  type RFunctorConstraint f :: * -> Constraint
  fmapR :: (RFunctorConstraint f a, RFunctorConstraint f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

-- Modulo the issues with unusual `Eq` and `Ord` instances, we might have
instance RFunctor Set where
  type RFunctorConstraint f = Ord
  fmapR = S.map
```

(Often, you'll see stuff about restricted monads; it's the same idea.)

Or, [as jozefg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20297050/237428), you could just write your own `treeMap` function and not put it in a type class.  Nothing wrong with that.

Note, however, that you should be careful when making `SortBinTree` a functor; the following is *not* `fmap`.  (It is, however, what `deriving (..., Functor)` will produce, so don't use that.)

```
notFmap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> SortBinTree a -> SortBinTree b
notFmap f EmptyNode    = EmptyNode
notFmap f (Node x l r) = Node (f x) (notFmap l) (notFmap r)
```

Why not?  Consider `notFmap negate (Node 2 (Node 1 EmptyNode EmptyNode) EmptyNode)`.  That will produce the tree `Node (-2) (Node (-1) EmptyNode EmptyNode) EmptyNode)`, which presumably violates your invariants – it's sorted backwards.²  So make sure your `fmap` is invariant-preserving.  `Data.Set` splits these into [`map`, which makes sure the invariants are preserved,](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Set.html#v:map) and [`mapMonotonic`, which requires you to pass in an order-preserving function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Set.html#v:mapMonotonic).  This latter function has the simple implementation, à la `notFmap`, but could produce invalid `Set`s if given uncooperative functions.

---

¹ [The `Data.Functor` module also exposes the `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> a` type class method](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-), but that's just there in case `fmap . const` has a faster implementation.

² However, `notFmap` *is* `fmap` from the subcategory of **Hask** whose objects are types with an `Ord` instance and whose morphisms are *order-preserving maps* to a subcategory of **Hask** whose objects are `SortBinTree`s over types with an `Ord` instance.  (Modulo some potential concerns about "uncooperative" `Eq`/`Ord` instances like those that mess with `Set` being a `Functor`.)

Comment: About footnote 2. Yes, it does form a functor from an ordered subcategory of **Hask** to a subcategory of `SortBinTree` with ordered `a`s. In essence, `Functor` is a proper endofunctor, `F : Hask -> Hask`, but we want a more refined notion of `RestrictedF : exists C <= Hask, D <= Hask, C -> D` which is a functor between subcategories of `Hask`. The reason we don't have this is purely a historical accident as the provides a strict superset of our current `Functor`.

Comment: @jozefg Ah, thanks.  I fixed the easy-to-fix bit from your comment.

Answer (score 5):

There are two choices, if your type satisfies the functor laws then the correct trick is

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data SortBinTree a = EmptyNode
                   | Node a (SortBinTree a) (SortBinTree a)
                   deriving Functor
-- Or a manual instance if you have some invariants that
-- need additional jiggering.
```

And make sure that all it's operations demand an `Ord` instance. If someone decides to put the tree in a useless state, then it's their own job to fix it.

However for this to work than you must satisfy the functor laws

```
 fmap id         === id
 fmap f . fmap g === fmap (f . g)
```

So if you remove duplicates at all from your tree, you're going to be in [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177125/sets-functors-and-eq-confusion). This is why `Data.Set` being an instance of `Functor` is dubious, it breaks this law.

If you break the laws, then you're simply not a functor. You cannot specify to Haskell that you only want to deal with a subcategory of `Hask`. In this case you should just define a different function

```
treeMap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> SortBinTree a -> SortBinTree b
```

In a category theoretic sense, this is still a functor, just not the one that `Functor` talks about.

Comment: What is the standard `Set`? Do you mean `Data.Set`? Then it seems, that it is not a member of Haskell's `Functor` type class. If it is, could you, please, point me to some reference?

Comment: @jozefg But as fiktor said, `Set` is *not* a `Functor`, and the lawlessness is exactly why.

Comment: @AntalS-Z Sorry, I misread the docs, I've updated my answer to be a bit clearer.

Comment: @fiktor Sorry I missed your comment edit, I've updated to make it clear.

Comment: In the [example][1] you referenced `fmap` breaks the functor's composition law just because `unWrap` breaks the mathematical law
(if a=b then f(a) = f(b)).

So I think `Data.Set` should be an instance of `Functor`, because it satisfies `Functor` law for all "normal" functions.


[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177125/sets-functors-and-eq-confusion

Comment: @fiktor Did you read the quoted comments below? The substitution property is desirable, but sometimes too strong. Indeed the Haskell report avoids mentioning **any** laws concerning `Eq` and `Ord`.

Comment: @jozefg: +1, but I hate to bring up one more issue – `deriving Functor` probably won't produce the right `fmap` for a *sorted* binary tree; consider `fmap negate`.  (You could probably *write* a fine `fmap`, but you can't `derive` it, so it's a minor point.)