# How to add a (Vector v a) constraint to an instance declaration?

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
newtype Matrix (w :: Nat) (h :: Nat) v a where
    Matrix :: v a -> Matrix w h v a
```

(where v a is `Data.Vector.Generic.Vector v a`, how do you say this?)

and:

```
instance Foldable (Matrix w h v) where
    foldMap = foldMapTree

foldMapTree :: (Vector v a, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> Matrix w h v a -> m
```

GHC complains about:

```
Matrix.hs:55:15:
    Could not deduce (Vector v a) arising from a use of ‘foldMapTree’
    from the context (Monoid m)
```

Changing to:

```
instance Vector v a => Foldable (Matrix w h v) where
    foldMap = foldMapTree
```

Gives:

```
Matrix.hs:54:10:
    Variable ‘a’ occurs more often than in the instance head
      in the constraint: Vector v a
      (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
```

Using `UndecidableInstances` doesn't help much as it breaks almost everything else ... there is probably a simple solution to this problem ... other answers suggest `UndecidableInstances` are not "bad" per se. But apparently I can't get this to work ...

Comment: Adding `UndecidableInstances` should never break existing code, it only allows more programs.

Comment: You can't make `Matrix n m` an instance of `Functor` for the same reason you can't make [`Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177125/sets-functors-and-eq-confusion) or [sorted binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296936/is-it-possible-to-create-a-functor-instance-for-sorted-binary-trees-in-haskell) an instance of `Functor`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `Data.Vector.Generic`?  I think it would be much simpler if you restricted yourself to `Data.Vector`.

Comment: @JohnL I'd need boxed and unboxed matrices.

Comment: @user2407038 but then why can ghc actually derive the Foldable instance? `deriving instance Foldable v    => Foldable (Matrix w h v)` works (with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`), it just doesn't have the right folding 'order' I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, what you want is not possible. The `Foldable` class expresses the idea that for a given type constructor, `Matrix w h v` in your case, you can do certain things for *any* argument type `a`.

However your `foldMapTree` only works for a restricted range of types, namely those where there is a `Vector v a` instance.

Even if you got your `instance Vector v a => Foldable (Matrix w h v)` past the type-checker, it wouldn't help because it wouldn't express the idea that you need `Vector v a` to hold for all possible `a` types, not just a particular one.

Comment: Like I answered user2407038 above: GHC can derive the `Foldable` instance just fine (using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, ie using the `Foldable` instance of `Vector`. I guess it should be possible for me to do the same should it?

Comment: If you can write your `foldMapTree` implementation without the `Vector` constraint, then that'll be fine.

Comment: [And conversely, if you can't, the reason for that will be the reason the instance you want isn't possible]

Comment: Now ... actually I could just relying on `F.toList` and working on that. But you are right, stupid me ...

Comment: Still, I could write the right instance for a "un-generic" matrix ... what exactly is preventing me from doing the same with the generic one?

Comment: @Florian: the ghc-derived Foldable instance doesn't work with generic or unboxed vectors, because there's no Foldable instance for those types.  The difference is that the basic boxed Vector has no constraints on the element type at all, but unboxed vectors do (and hence generic vectors do also).