# Foldable vs Traversable

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, foldable, traversable

While studying `Applicative` deeper, I came to `Traversable`. Although I already knew `Foldable` from [LYHGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids), I haven't seen the former yet, so I started reading the [Haskell wiki about Traversable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Traversable).

While reading it, I understood why `Foldable.fold` is parallel to `Traversable.sequenceA` and `Foldable.foldMap` is parallel to `Traversable.traverse`.

I've seen also that every `Traversable` is also a `Foldable` and a `Functor`, and `sequenceA` and `traversal` have a default implementation in terms of each other:

```
traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f
sequenceA = traverse id
```

So, as I have seen in LYHGG that `foldMap` is a minimal complete definition for `Foldable`, I thought that, it is parallel to `traverse`, so `fold` (which is parallel to `sequenceA`) would be a minimal complete definition too (which it isn't)... `Foldable` is not a `Functor` like `Traversable` is, so we cannot apply this:

```
foldMap f = fold . fmap f
fold = foldMap id -- this is ok
```

Why isn't every `Foldable` a `Functor`, and what would be an instance of `Foldable` that actually isn't a `Functor`?

Comment: `Set` is a classic example of a `Foldable` that's not a `Functor`. So are unboxed vectors.

Comment: @dfeuer I will read more about `Set` to understand why it isn't a `Functor`, but, Sets can be thought as containers of things that don't repeat... That being said, I cannot figure out quickly why it is not a `Functor` instance...

Comment: The trouble is that `Functor` doesn't give implementations the opportunity to constrain their type arguments. Imagine if someone wrote `fmap f s` where `f :: Int -> Integer -> Integer`. The type `Integer -> Integer` is not even an instance of `Eq`, let alone `Ord`, so there's no way to check for duplicates when mapping. The function could map multiple elements to identical functions, and you'd have no way of collapsing the duplicates.

Comment: Unboxed vectors can only contain "unboxable" things, so if `xs :: U.Vector Int`, `fmap Just xs` would have to produce something of type `U.Vector (Maybe Int)`, which isn't a real thing.

Comment: As I understand things, the `Traversable` class was conceived first (e.g., McBride and Patterson, ["Applicative Programming with Effects"](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html); Gibbons and Oliveira, ["The Essence of the Iterator Pattern"](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf)). `Foldable` was added as a superclass because of the "containers that aren't `Functor`s" problem. But `foldMap` falls out of `traverse`-ing with the `Const` applicative, as shown in Gibbons and Oliveira's paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As dfeuer says, `Set` is a good example of a `Foldable` that isn't a `Functor`.

Consider the type of `Set.map`:

```
map :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

Notice that this is *almost* `fmap`, but it requires an additional `Ord b` constraint. Since you have this constraint, it can't be made an instance of `Functor`.

Note that `Set` is not a functor on Haskell, even with this restriction. Given cleverly set-up `Eq` instances we can break the law that `fmap f . fmap g === fmap (f . g)`. See this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19177125/371753) for further discussion.

As noted there, `Set` *is* an (endo) functor on the "subcategory of `Hask`" with ordered types as sets and with *order-preserving maps* as morphisms.

So even if it isn't apparent, the fact that we can't make `Set` a functor actually hints at a genuine mathematical issue and not just a limitation of our typeclass machinery.

Comment: what I think that is amazing is that mathematically it is a `Functor` but because of this constraint it cannot be an `instance` of the `Functor` typeclass... Don't you think that this resembles an "imperfection" in the language? (The language is really beautiful, concise, and powerful, anyway!)

Comment: @FtheBuilder I edited my answer to describe more context.

Comment: I know I should not say "Thank you" in a comment, but really, your explanations were veeeery interesting! :D

Comment: The "order-preserving maps as morphisms" thing seems quite restrictive; naively I would think "equality-preserving" would be enough. Can you comment on that a bit?

Comment: @DanielWagner, I wondered the same thing. Order-preserving gets you efficiency, but I don't see it being absolutely essential.

Comment: You're probably write that equality preserving is enough. I used order preserving because that's typically how it is presented (can't find a reference off hand) and because its typical to have ordered sets with order preserving maps, so its a more "natural" setting. But I can't think why its actually necessary.

Comment: Indeed order-preserving is not necessary. And “equality-preserving” is pretty much a _universal_ requirement, at least when you're talking about actual semantic equalities (`==` is only a rough approximation to equality; if you use that as a benchmark then tough luck applying the monad laws to anything interesting). Thus, `Set` **is** a functor on the ord-constrained **Hask** category, or [indeed a monad on all of **Hask**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad) if you implement it cleverly.