# Recursively walking an AST using foldl and the Reader monad without boilerplate

Tags: haskell, monads, fold, parsec, reader-monad

I'm traversing [an AST](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/47e40f0e4f64098bbb4bceccf74e88756ac7d2f6/lib/Docvim/AST.hs#L7-L59) using [simple pattern matching](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/47e40f0e4f64098bbb4bceccf74e88756ac7d2f6/lib/Docvim/Printer/Markdown.hs#L31-L57) and [the `Reader` monad](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/47e40f0e4f64098bbb4bceccf74e88756ac7d2f6/lib/Docvim/Printer/Markdown.hs#L24-L26).

Elsewhere in my project I've defined [a `walk` function](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/47e40f0e4f64098bbb4bceccf74e88756ac7d2f6/lib/Docvim/AST.hs#L100-L111) for traversing the AST, which at its heart uses `foldl` to reduce the results of visiting each node in the tree into a single monoidal result (for example, [to produce a "symbol table"](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/47e40f0e4f64098bbb4bceccf74e88756ac7d2f6/lib/Docvim/Visitor/Symbol.hs#L11-L32) from the special nodes in the tree).

My question is: is it possible to combine these two approaches and use a function like my `walk` function:

```
walk :: Monoid a => (Node -> a) -> a -> Node -> a
walk f acc n = foldl (walk f) (acc <> f n) children
  where
    children = case n of
      Blockquote b           -> b
      DocBlock d             -> d
      FunctionDeclaration {} -> functionBody n
      List l                 -> l
      ListItem i             -> i
      Paragraph p            -> p
      Unit u                 -> u
      _                      -> [] -- no Node children
```

and the `Reader` — like the traversal in the code below (some bits omitted for brevity) — at the same time?

```
markdown :: Node -> String
markdown n = runReader (node n) state
  where state = State (getSymbols n) (getPluginName n)

node :: Node -> Env
node n = case n of
  Blockquote b            -> blockquote b >>= appendNewline >>= appendNewline
  DocBlock d              -> nodes d
  FunctionDeclaration {}  -> nodes $ functionBody n
  Paragraph p             -> nodes p >>= appendNewline >>= appendNewline
  Link l                  -> link l
  List ls                 -> nodes ls >>= appendNewline
  ListItem l              -> fmap ("- " ++) (nodes l) >>= appendNewline
  Unit u                  -> nodes u
```

My use motivation here is that my `walk` function already encodes the knowledge of how to do get the children for each pattern and how to perform an in-order traversal of the AST. I don't really want to reimplement that for every traversal, so it would be nice to use `walk` in more places, including ones where I need to use `Reader` (and likely later on, `State`, probably in a stack).

Can these things be fruitfully combined?

Comment: I don't know and I don't have time to look in depth right now, but I'm guessing you should look less at `foldl` and more at `traverse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A lensy approach

A moment for generic programming to shine! This very problem, the problem of folding over a recursive datatype without boilerplate, is the motivation for the [uniplate/biplate library](http://ndmitchell.com/downloads/slides-uniform_boilerplate_and_list_processing-30_sep_2007.pdf). That design now lives on in its most modern form in [`Control.Lens.Plated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) c/o the `lens` package. To take advantage of it:

- Turn on `DeriveDataTypeable` and add `deriving (Data)` to your `Node`, `ArgumentList`, `Argument`.
- Right away you're able to take advantage of `uniplate` from `Data.Data.Lens`. This is a traversal, an object that – when passed to the right lens helpers – will yield you all the values of type `Node` inside a given `Node`. Basically it runs one step of your recursive `walk` function.
- An example:

  ```
  λ> Blockquote [BreakTag, Blockquote [BreakTag]] ^.. uniplate
  [BreakTag,Blockquote [BreakTag]]
  λ> Blockquote [BreakTag, Blockquote [BreakTag]] ^.. uniplate . uniplate
  [BreakTag]
  λ> Blockquote [BreakTag, Blockquote [BreakTag]] ^.. uniplate . uniplate . uniplate
  []
  ```
- But wait, there's more. If `uniplate` is one small step for generics, then `cosmosOf uniplate` is one large step for programmerkind. `cosmosOf` repeatedly uses `uniplate` to retrieve the children, grandchildren, greatgrandchildren, and so on from a given `Node`.

  ```
  λ> Blockquote [BreakTag, Blockquote [BreakTag]] ^..  cosmosOf uniplate
  [ Blockquote [BreakTag,Blockquote [BreakTag]]
  , BreakTag
  , Blockquote [BreakTag]
  , BreakTag]
  ```
- In both examples, we're taking advantage of how compositional `lens` traversals (and folds) are. The hierarchy of lens and why they compose so well is beyond the confines of this little textbox, but suffice it to say that they're super mega useful.
- Use the `foldlOf` helper in `Control.Lens.Fold` to implement your `walk` function:

  ```
  walk' :: Monoid a => (Node -> a) -> a -> Node -> a
  walk' f acc n =
    foldlOf (cosmosOf uniplate . to f) (<>) acc n
  ```

  Not so bad. `to f` creates a getter from your `f` and it's composed with the cosmic fold to reach all the descendants; each value from this getter is folded and accumulated into our monoid.

As for `node`, you'll have to build a custom fold. `cosmosOf uniplate` doesn't work so well here because sometimes you short-circuit the recursion (e.g. in the `Blockquote` case). You'll have to write `cosmosOf foo` and build `foo` piecemeal out of [lens helpers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#g:3); note you can still use `uniplate` to discharge most of the cases in your custom fold. This is quite a large bit of code and it's getting awful late, so I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader. I'm 90% certain it's possible.

As for the reader monad, you can either use `foldlMOf` or note that `type Env = Reader State String` is isomorphic to `State -> String` and note that `State -> String` has a `Monoid` instance because `Monoid String` exists. This all means that you should be able to implement `node` with the non-monadic `foldlOf`, like we did above – all we really want to do is concatenate a bunch of monoidal values, in the end.

This solution isn't perfect: it requires future code readers to know a good bit of knowledge about lens and how traversals/folds/getters gel with `Data.Data` and why these functions all have funny little `Of` suffixes on them. But you must admit that there's a beautiful sort of conciseness and power to `Plated` that abstracts away the boring recursion part of folding over custom datatypes so you only have to pattern match on the leaves of the data structure (like `BreakTag` in `node`) and edge cases (like `Blockquote` in `node`).

Answer (score 3):

Your `walk` function looks very much like the `Foldable` class, which is the superclass of `Traversable` (which dfeuer also points out in a comment).  In your position I'd have a look at the [`mono-traversable` package](https://www.stackage.org/package/mono-traversable).

But I have a hunch that your `Node` type won't actually turn out to be a good `MonoTraversable` instance as currently formulated.  The reason, informally, is that there isn't a good separation between these concepts:

1. The *structure* of the AST: which nodes are the children of which.
2. The *content* of the AST: the "attributes" at each node.

One very informal way to think of the `Functor` and `Traversable` classes is that they operate on the "content" of a value without altering is "structure" (but [beware of taking that analogy too literally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177125/sets-functors-and-eq-confusion/19192745#19192745)).  I considered writing a `MonoTraversable` instance for your `Node` type but backed off quickly after some thought:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.MonoTraversable

-- Here is the root of the problem.  The type function 
-- `Element` is supposed to pick out which pieces of a 
-- `Node` are its "content" as opposed to its "structure,"
-- but with `Node` as formulated there isn't a distinction!
type instance Element Node = Node
```

Given that, the `otraverse` method, which has this principal type:

```
otraverse :: Applicative f => (Element mono -> f (Element mono)) -> mono -> f mono
```

...would end up with this specialized type when `mono := Node`:

```
otraverse :: Applicative f => (Node -> f Node) -> Node -> f Node
```

...and I'm worried that somebody could try to call `otraverse` with a function that discards the children of the root node, e.g., how evil is it when somebody attempts `otraverse (return Separator)`?

I haven't checked whether these instances are unlawful for sure, so I might be worried over nothing here, it's worth checking if I'm wrong.  But it certainly "smells bad" according to my design sense.

---

So what to do?  I'd look into reformulating the `Node` type a little bit, splitting it into two types:

1. A `Content` type that expresses the information that is visible at each step of the left-to-right walk of the AST, but not how the `Content`s nest;
2. A `Structure` type that defines the possible shapes of the tree—how the `Content`s nest.

Once that is done, you'd be able to reformulate your `walk` function like this:

```
walk :: Monoid a => (Content -> a) -> a -> Structure -> a
```

Note that the second argument of this function (the initial `acc :: Monoid a => a` value) is superfluous, these two functions look interdefinable:

```
walk' :: Monoid a => (Content -> a) -> Structure -> a
walk' f = walk f mempty

walk :: Monoid a => (Content -> a) -> a -> Structure -> a
walk f acc tree = acc <> walk' f tree
```

And my `walk'` signature then looks like it would be the `ofoldMap` method from `mono-traversable`:

```
ofoldMap :: Monoid m => (Element mono -> m) -> mono -> m
```

Which then would make it natural to ask whether you can implement `MonoTraversable` for your reformulated type and get the `otraverse` operation whose signature I mentioned above, which specialized with `f := Reader r`, and `mono := Structure` and `Element mono := Content` would be:

```
otraverse :: (Content -> Reader r Content) -> Structure -> Reader r Structure
```