# Patterns for managing/representing selection from a set of options in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, powerset

Algebraic data types make it easy to allow one item from a set to be selected: just use an appropriate sum type.

I'm curious how one would implement the option of selecting strictly n items or fewer from a set. I can see how it might be possible to implement this with Data.Set, but I wonder if there's a pattern or an algebraic structure that would be more robust.

Say a burger can have three toppings from the set Pickle | Onion | Lettuce | Tomato etc. It's reasonable to want to display all the options in a UI, so if we use Data.Set, right away I notice that Data.Set.all is missing, so there's no easy way to print all the values that can be selected. But Data.Set.powerSet is available, so I'm thinking maybe I should be getting the user to choose an element of the subset of the power set with cardinality <= 3.

Using an element of the power set to represent a selection from the base set seems like a good idea. It doesn't look much like any UI I can think of, though. The power set functor is a monad, though I'm not sure if this is relevant (See discussion about power set as a functor here [Sets, Functors and Eq confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177125/sets-functors-and-eq-confusion)).

Maybe someone who has solved a similar problem before will have advice on how to best make this work. I'm really looking for conceptual insights into what an "n choose k" type looks like, if that makes sense.

Comment: Would `Maybe (Topping, Maybe (Topping, Maybe Topping))` do? It can only contain at most three toppings (possibly equal ones). It's not terribly convenient to use, though.

Comment: @chi `Just (Onion, Just (Pickle, Just Tomato))` vs .`Just (Onion, Just (Tomato, Just Pickle))`? Not good, even if we ignore that it permits duplicates.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You could adapt that approach using GADT to ensure a fixed ordering, which would remove duplicates. It looks overkill to me. Perhaps using a looser type representation and guaranteeing the 3-elements property using smart constructors is more practical than trying to enforce everything at static time.

Comment: Yeah, just wrapping a `Set` with a `Nat` phantom type argument seems the most sensible approach. For “all the values that can be selected”, instantiate [`Universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.2.1/docs/Data-Universe.html#t:Universe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer, of sorts.

Here are a few extensions and imports needed for the rest of the code below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
```

As you're probably aware, the nice thing about representing a single item as an ADT:

```
data Topping = Pickle | Onion | Lettuce | Tomato deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

is that the definition of the type makes it impossible to represent anything other than exactly one choice of `Topping`, provided we ignore the possibility of having an `undefined` value.  It's equally easy to represent "up to one choice of `Topping`" in this foolproof way, using a `Maybe` type:

```
type UpToOneTopping = Maybe Topping
```

We can also represent zero or more (including a possibly infinite number of) toppings, with possible duplicates, using a list:

```
type ManyToppings = [Topping]
```

However, it's difficult to represent a set of toppings without duplicates this same way.  We can use the `Set Topping` type, but we're no longer relying on the type system to make sets with duplicates unrepresentable.  Instead, we're relying on the implementation of the `Set` type in the `containers` package, and the restricted interface it provides, to guarantee that the set won't contain any duplicates.  If we dug into the guts of the `Set` implementation, we'd probably discover that the internal representation can allow sets with duplicates, and we're relying on the correctness of the code written by the `Set` author to make sure this can't happen.

In contrast, the `Topping` type above makes a stronger guarantee than this, making anything other than a single type unrepresentable by construction.  (Well, I guess you could say we're relying on the correctness of the compiler, but it's common to think of this kind of guarantee as "stronger" than one that relies on the correctness of the `Set` implementation.)

In a similar vein to the `Set` type, it would be possible to use an `UpToThree Topping` type to represent a set of zero to three distinct toppings, but the guarantee would be provided by the implementation and its sanctioned interface, not by the data representation itself.  That is, we could write:

```
newtype UpToThree a = UpToThree (Set a)

upToThree :: (Ord a) => [a] -> UpToThree a
upToThree xs | length xs' > 3 = error "no more than three allowed"
             | otherwise = UpToThree xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs
```

If we only create `UpToThree` values via this `upToThree` "smart constructor" (either through programmer discipline or using Haskell's package system to limit the interface exported to users of the data type), then we can provide a guarantee of sorts that any `UpToThree` value will represent no more than three distinct `a` values.

In practical Haskell code, this is probably the most reasonable approach.  One limitation is that it requires a separate new type for each up-to-`k` number.  We could make the number a field in the data type:

```
data UpToK a = UpToK Int (Set a)

upToK :: (Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> UpToK a
upToK k xs | length xs' > k = error "too many"
             | otherwise = UpToK k xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs
```

but this `UpToK` type is much less useful than it might first appear.  The problem is that the smart constructor ensures that a particular `UpToK` represents a number of distinct values of type `a` that's no more than than the count given by the integer field `k` encoded in the value, so it ensures consistency between the two fields in the value, but the type system doesn't enforce anything about `k`, so if we have a function that requires no more than three toppings using the original `UpToThree`:

```
data Burger = Burger
placeOnBurger :: UpToThree Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger u = undefined
```

we can ensure through a type signature using `UpToThree` that we receive no more than three toppings, provided the implementation of the `UpToThree` type is sound, but if we try to write an `UpToK` version, we end up having to inspect the field anyway to ensure our precondition is met:

```
placeOnBurger' :: UpToK Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger' (UpToK k _) | k > 3 = error "no one can fit so many toppings!"
placeOnBurger' u = undefined
```

which means we could have just checked the length of a `Set` directly and didn't need the `UpToK` type at all:

```
placeOnBurger'' :: Set Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger'' s | length s > 3 = error "too many toppings for a burger"
placeOnBurger'' s = undefined
```

Fortunately, there is a way to use the `DataKinds` extension, to index a collection of types by a non-negative number.  With a few other extensions, this allows us to write:

```
newtype UpTo (k :: Nat) a = UpTo (Set a)
upTo :: forall k a. (KnownNat k, Ord a) => [a] -> UpTo k a
upTo xs | length xs' > fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy @k)) = error "too many"
        | otherwise = UpTo xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs
```

This `UpTo` type is much more useful than `UpToK`.  It still relies on a protected `upTo` smart constructor to ensure that only valid `UpTo` values are produced, but the upper limit is now part of the type, so we can write:

```
placeOnBurger''' :: UpTo 3 Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger''' s = undefined
```

and we have a strong, type system guarantee that this version of `placeOnBurger'''` will only be called with an `UpTo 3 Topping` value, which implies a (weaker) smart constructor guarantee that the number of toppings passed will be no more than three.

If you want the stronger guarantee of encoding the topping limit in the type so that it's enforced by the type system itself, the same way `Maybe Topping` enforces a zero-or-one topping rule, then it's possible, but it can quickly get unwieldy.

One method is to use a GADT in combination with a Peano natural that's automatically promoted to the type level by the `DataKinds` extension:

```
data Peano = Z | S Peano
```

It's also helpful to have a type-level function for converting from plain type-level naturals to these Peano type-level naturals:

```
type family P n where
  P 0 = Z
  P n = S (P (n-1))
```

Then we can easily create a GADT representing a list of "no more than `n`" elements:

```
-- a list of no more than `n` elements of type `a`
data LimitedList (n :: Peano) a where
  Empty :: LimitedList n a
  Cons :: a -> LimitedList n a -> LimitedList (S n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (LimitedList n a)
```

It takes a little study to understand why this representation works, but observe what happens in GHCi when we try to create a 3-element list whose type-level limits are 3, 5, and 2:

```
λ> 1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Int
...works...
λ> 1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 5) Int
...works...
λ> 1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 2) Int
...generates a type error...
```

The downside of this GADT is that it allows duplicates and doesn't provide a unique representation, so if we had multiple representations of pickles and onions as a no-more-than-3 list of toppings:

```
top1 = Pickle `Cons` Onion `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping
top2 = Onion `Cons` Pickle `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping
top3 = Onion `Cons` Pickle `Cons` Onion `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping
```

but wanted them to be treated uniformly (compare as equal, generate the same list of toppings in the same order when we run `toList` on them, etc.), we'd end up having to write some more code to provide these (weak) guarantees.

To answer another part of your question, it's possible to write a function to generate all valid `LimitedList`s of a certain size for any enumerable type, though the output will include these duplicates and alternative representations.  Writing such a function requires the use of a so-called "singleton" representation for the Peano naturals:

```
data SPeano n where
  SZ :: SPeano Z
  SS :: SPeano n -> SPeano (S n)

allLimitedLists :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => SPeano n -> [LimitedList n a]
allLimitedLists SZ = [Empty]
allLimitedLists (SS n) = [x `Cons` xs | x <- [minBound..maxBound]
                           , xs <- rest]
                         ++ map levelUp rest
  where rest = allLimitedLists n
        levelUp :: LimitedList n a -> LimitedList (S n) a
        levelUp Empty = Empty
        levelUp (x `Cons` xs) = x `Cons` levelUp xs

all3Toppings :: [LimitedList (P 3) Topping]
all3Toppings = allLimitedLists (SS (SS (SS SZ)))

main = print all3Toppings
```

The rather strange `levelUp` function here is an expensive identity function, at least at the term level.  (At the type level, it's not the identity, which is kind of the point.)  Anyway, it's an unfortunate artifact of the choice of representation of `LimitedList`. Ironically, it can be safely replaced with `levelUp = unsafeCoerce`.  At least, I think it can.  It seems to work, at any rate.

Before I give one last approach, here's all the code so far in case you want to play with it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Topping = Pickle | Onion | Lettuce | Tomato deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

type UpToOneTopping = Maybe Topping

type ManyToppings = [Topping]

newtype UpToThree a = UpToThree (Set a)

upToThree :: (Ord a) => [a] -> UpToThree a
upToThree xs | length xs' > 3 = error "no more than three allowed"
             | otherwise = UpToThree xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs

data UpToK a = UpToK Int (Set a)

upToK :: (Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> UpToK a
upToK k xs | length xs' > k = error "too many"
             | otherwise = UpToK k xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs

data Burger = Burger
placeOnBurger :: UpToThree Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger u = undefined

placeOnBurger' :: UpToK Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger' (UpToK k _) | k > 3 = error "no one can fit so many toppings!"
placeOnBurger' u = undefined

placeOnBurger'' :: Set Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger'' s | length s > 3 = error "too many toppings for a burger"
placeOnBurger'' s = undefined

newtype UpTo (k :: Nat) a = UpTo (Set a)
upTo :: forall k a. (KnownNat k, Ord a) => [a] -> UpTo k a
upTo xs | length xs' > fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy @k)) = error "too many"
        | otherwise = UpTo xs'
  where xs' = Set.fromList xs

placeOnBurger''' :: UpTo 3 Topping -> Burger
placeOnBurger''' s = undefined

data Peano = Z | S Peano

type family P n where
  P 0 = Z
  P n = S (P (n-1))

-- a list of no more than `n` elements of type `a`
data LimitedList (n :: Peano) a where
  Empty :: LimitedList n a
  Cons :: a -> LimitedList n a -> LimitedList (S n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (LimitedList n a)

top1 = Pickle `Cons` Onion `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping
top2 = Onion `Cons` Pickle `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping
top3 = Onion `Cons` Pickle `Cons` Onion `Cons` Empty :: LimitedList (P 3) Topping

data SPeano n where
  SZ :: SPeano Z
  SS :: SPeano n -> SPeano (S n)

allLimitedLists :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => SPeano n -> [LimitedList n a]
allLimitedLists SZ = [Empty]
allLimitedLists (SS n) = [x `Cons` xs | x <- [minBound..maxBound]
                           , xs <- rest]
                         ++ map levelUp rest
  where rest = allLimitedLists n
        levelUp :: LimitedList n a -> LimitedList (S n) a
        levelUp Empty = Empty
        levelUp (x `Cons` xs) = x `Cons` levelUp xs

all3Toppings :: [LimitedList (P 3) Topping]
all3Toppings = allLimitedLists (SS (SS (SS SZ)))

main = print all3Toppings
```

Finally, it *is* possible to enforce a unique, duplicate-free representation at the type level, but it adds another layer of complexity and makes the type *much* more difficult to use.  Here's one way to do it by encoding the minimum element in the type and using a constraint to permit only smaller elements to be prepended.  I've used the `singletons` package to take care of some of the boilerplate, so we'll require quite a few extensions plus some imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
```

We'll need singletons for both our Peano naturals and our `Topping` type, as we'll see below.

```
$(singletons [d|
  data Peano = Z | S Peano
  data Topping = Pickle | Onion | Lettuce | Tomato deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
  |])
```

Here, we use `promote` to define type functions `P` and `Before`.  These could have been defined using type families, but promoting plain Haskell functions gives nicer syntax.

```
$(promote [d|
  p 0 = Z
  p n = S (p (n-1))

  before _ Nothing = True
  before x (Just y) = x < y
  |])
```

Our limited set will be represented by the following GADT, which represents a (strictly) ascending list of elements of type `a` whose head (smallest) element is `h`, and which contains no more than `n` elements.  We use the `Before` type function here to permit an `x` value to be prepended to a list only if it's strictly less than the list's head element.

```
data MinLimitedSet (n :: Peano) (h :: Maybe a) where
  Empty' :: MinLimitedSet n Nothing
  Cons' :: (Before x min ~ True) => Sing x -> MinLimitedSet n min -> MinLimitedSet (S n) (Just x)
infixr 5 `Cons'`
```

Using this `MinLimitedSet` type in code would require specifying the minimum element of the list in the type signatures.  That's not very convenient, so we provide an existential type `LimitedSet` that represents a `MinLimitedSet` with an unspecified minimum element:

```
data LimitedSet (n :: Peano) a where
  LimitedSet :: MinLimitedSet n (h :: Maybe a) -> LimitedSet n a
```

With these GADTs in place, we can define an example value:

```
top1' :: LimitedSet (P 3) Topping
top1' = LimitedSet $ sing @Pickle `Cons'` sing @Onion `Cons'` Empty'
```

Note that this definition is valid only because `Pickle` and `Onion` are in strictly ascending order (according to the `Ord` instance for `Topping`) and there are no more than three elements being combined.  If you try to create a list of too many toppings, or a list with duplicates or out of strictly ascending order, you'll get a compile-time type error.  To use such lists in programs, you'll typically want to convert them to plain term-level lists, and that's what the `toList` function does.

```
toList :: forall n a. (SingKind a) => LimitedSet n a -> [Demote a]
toList (LimitedSet asc) = go asc
  where go :: forall n lst. MinLimitedSet n lst -> [Demote a]
        go (Empty') = []
        go (x `Cons'` xs) = fromSing x : go xs

main = print $ toList top1'
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
  data Peano = Z | S Peano
  data Topping = Pickle | Onion | Lettuce | Tomato deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
  |])

$(promote [d|
  p 0 = Z
  p n = S (p (n-1))

  before _ Nothing = True
  before x (Just y) = x < y
  |])

data MinLimitedSet (n :: Peano) (h :: Maybe a) where
  Empty' :: MinLimitedSet n Nothing
  Cons' :: (Before x min ~ True) => Sing x -> MinLimitedSet n min -> MinLimitedSet (S n) (Just x)
infixr 5 `Cons'`
data LimitedSet (n :: Peano) a where
  LimitedSet :: MinLimitedSet n (h :: Maybe a) -> LimitedSet n a

top1' :: LimitedSet (P 3) Topping
top1' = LimitedSet $ sing @Pickle `Cons'` sing @Onion `Cons'` Empty'

toList :: forall n a. (SingKind a) => LimitedSet n a -> [Demote a]
toList (LimitedSet asc) = go asc
  where go :: forall n lst. MinLimitedSet n lst -> [Demote a]
        go (Empty') = []
        go (x `Cons'` xs) = fromSing x : go xs

main = print $ toList top1'
```